# How to disable linux OOM killer for processes using the java service wrapper?

Tags: linux, java-service-wrapper

We are having an issue where the out of memory killer is killing our process due to the out of the box overcommit memory settings on CentOS.

After researching this quite a bit, I think the best thing to do is to tell the OOM killer to never kill the process, as described here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

To do this, we need to execute the following command after startup:

echo -17 > /proc/{pid}/oom_adj

I was thinking this could be done as part of the *.sh script that gets executed via the java service wrapper, but I am not sure exactly how to do this (mainly where in this script I can put the valid logic). I am hoping someone might have done this before that could help.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `ps aux | grep name-of-jar | awk...` to get the pid of the running java service and then `echo` with the pid path.

Comment: Just to state the obvious, in addition to protecting your java process from the OOM killer you also need to resolve the configuration problem which leads to OOMs in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for both the replies. Yes I agree, this is a short term solution as a stop gap. @Avihoo, this makes sense, but I am asking specifically how to do this from within the java server wrapper. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? The java server wrapper triggers a `*.sh` script? if so, you can put it at the end of the script, don't you?